# Python default metaclasses

Tags: python, metaclass

Is it possible to somehow configure a python module or REPL to use a default metaclass for all classes defined, regardless of whether or not a metaclass is used in the class ?

```
class met(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(met, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        setattr(cls, "_test_member", "test_value")

class A(object):
    pass

>>> A._test_member
'test_value'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Pavel Anossov's (now deleted) comment:

```
class met(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(met, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        cls._test_member = "test_value"

object = met('object', (object,), {})

class A(object):
    pass

print(A._test_member)
```

prints

```
test_value
```

---

Note that a class can have only one metaclass. (Since, after all, any object can have only one type). But additionally, the metaclass of a class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases. In other words, the class's metaclass and the metaclasses of all its bases must either be the same, or all those metaclasses must be subclasses of each other. So the above solution may not work if a class tries to use a  metaclass which is not a subclass of `met`.

For example,

```
class met(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(met, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        cls._test_member = "test_value"

object = met('object', (object,), {})

class someothertype(type): pass

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = someothertype
```

raises

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Comment: I didn't know you can redefine object using itself as a base. Very sneaky.

Comment: @unutbu: I replaced `setattr(cls, "_test_member", "test_value")` with its more usual and direct form.

Comment: +1: this works even if the class defines `__metaclass__`, as the question required.

Answer (score 3):

On python 2.x you could just do

```
 __metaclass__ = met
```

in the beginning of the module and then define your class in old style mode:

```
class A:
    pass
```

On 3.x, this is no longer possible. Also, "Explicit is better than implicit."

Another approach, you could do:

```
class Object(metaclass=met):  # Py3k syntax
    pass
```

and always inherit from it.

Note: Calling the subclass of `type` is the only way to make use of metaclass compatible with both Py2k and Py3k. Like in [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480418/754991)'s answer

Comment: Is there a way to redefine the builtin object class to use a metaclass?

Comment: you can rebind it, like said in a comment above: `object = Object`

Comment: That would be incredibly dangerous, error-prone, and generally undesirable.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that's why I would name it with a capital `O`, so other people can know whats going on

Comment: @dilbert: Your question asked for `met` to be the meta-class, *regardless* of whether or not a metaclass is used in the class. Note that this answer does not work for Python 2 in the case of a class that defines an explicit metaclass. unutbu's method work in this case.